# Why do we need key when rendering a list of React Fragments?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, jsx

I'm learning React and it is specified that when [rendering a list of items](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#rendering-a-list-of-fragments), React needs `key` so that:

> Even if the position changes due to reordering, the key lets React identify the item throughout its lifetime.

And React also presents an interesting option for "[Rendering a list of Fragments](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#rendering-a-list-of-fragments)" as a way for "[Displaying several DOM nodes for each list item](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#displaying-several-dom-nodes-for-each-list-item)"

**My questions are**

1. Since Fragments are not rendered into DOM nodes, so when we render list of "Keyed Fragments", are their `key` attributes actually used by React (for optimization an whatnot)?
2. If it's true that Fragment's key are being used for some reasons, where are they stored? Cause from inspection of HTML elements I cannot find any properties with the key's value. (See example below)
3. If not, why even have key for each Fragment in a list of Fragments? Could it be just to bypass the `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`?

Example code for a list of fragments from `React.dev`

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';

// ...

const listItems = people.map(person =>
  <Fragment key={person.id}>
    <h1>{person.name}</h1>
    <p>{person.bio}</p>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Which results in the following HTML

```
...
<h1>Person 1 name</h1>
<p>I am 1</p>
<h1>Person 2 name</h1>
<p>I am 2</p>
...
```

But, when examining HTML attributes of the generated items, I cannot find any `key` attributes relating to React.

In usual cases where we render a list with normal containers with id (something like `<li key={person.id}>`), the resulting container in HTML will have `key` attribute in a `__reactFiber$...` property. But in the case of Fragments, there are no container, leading to no keys attached.

Here are two code example (from `React.dev`) of such two lists:

1. Normal `li` containers list: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/53r2y6?file=/data.js&utm_medium=sandpack)
2. Similar Fragments list: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cmq9l9?file=%2FApp.js&utm_medium=sandpack)

*Thank you!*

Comment: It is used in the virtual representation of the DOM so that react can infer if something has changed between the list renderings.